# Loading from 2 urlloaders in an order and maintaining the flow in FLEX

Tags: events, apache-flex, event-handling, synchronous

I have a flex application where on creationComplete i call a method in which i needed to load two XML files frm the server.only after which i need to proceed further..

Currently i am doing the following

```
onCreationComplete = init();    

private function init():void{

    //loading first XML

    urlReq = new URLRequest(PATH_FOR_XML1);
    urlLdr = new URLLoader(urlReq);
    urlLdr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, doEvent);

    //Some other operation  goes here say SOMEGREATWORK    
}

**doEvent method**

private function doEvent(evt:Event):void{

    //Loading the data of XML1 to some variable which i use application wide

    urlReq = new URLRequest(PATH_FOR_XML2);
    urlLdr = new URLLoader(urlReq);
    urlLdr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadXML2);
}

private function loadXML2(evt:Event):void{
    //Loading the data of XML2 to the some varibale which i use application Wide
}
```

What actually i was doing is ,once the loading of one URL completed, i load data from it and the starting the loading of second URL loader from the same method.

But the problem is 
i dont want SOMEGREATWORK block to be executed before the 2 XMLs are loaded to application variables

because in SOMEGREATWORK block , i will be using the them and by the time this executes, sometimes the variables are not loaded properly.

Comment: Why not start "some great work" in loadXML2?

Comment: yeah thats a good solution.. thanks donno how i missed this angle

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    onCreationComplete = init();


private function init():void{

    //loading first XML

    urlReq = new URLRequest(PATH_FOR_XML1);
    urlLdr = new URLLoader(urlReq);
    urlLdr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, doEvent);

}


private function doEvent(evt:Event):void{

    //Loading the data of XML1 to some variable which i use application wide


    urlReq = new URLRequest(PATH_FOR_XML2);
    urlLdr = new URLLoader(urlReq);
    urlLdr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadXML2);

}

private function loadXML2(evt:Event):void{
    //Some other operation  goes here say SOMEGREATWORK
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and suggestions, i have defined an event listener to the class and when ever i finish loading the xml2 i am dispathing the event so that the SOMEGREATWORK can be done on the event dispatch..

Comment: I think that's the same as the code I have above.  When the xml2 finishes loading, it triggers the loadXML2 (probably not the best function name, but copied quickly).  So the net result is that there is chained loading of the 2 xml files then at the end of the second, the SOMEGREATWORK is started.  Of course you're also going to want to put in error handlers so your chain can respond appropriately if the xml does not load for some reason.